# Create an SQL query from two tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as shown in the image. I want to create a SQL query in postgresql to get the `pkey` and minimum `count` for each unique 'pkey' in table 1 where 'name1' is not present in the array of column 'name' in table 2. 
'name' is a array
[image]

Comment: Good question, but you'd make it easier for people by providing text, not images. Ideal would be `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21127) to check if one element exists in your name's array.

> ```
> create table t1 (pkey int, cnt int);
> create table t2 (pkey int, name text[]);
>
> insert into t1 values (1, 11),(1, 9),(2, 14),(2, 15),(3, 21),(3,16);
> insert into t2 values
> (1, array['name1','name2']),
> (1, array['name3','name2']),
> (2, array['name4','name1']),
> (2, array['name5','name2']),
> (3, array['name2','name3']),
> (3, array['name4','name5']);
> ```

> ```
> select pkey
> from   t2
> where 'name1' = any(name);
> ```
>
> ```
> | pkey |
> | ---: |
> |    1 |
> |    2 |
> ```

> ```
> select   t1.pkey, min(cnt) count
> from     t1
> where    not exists (select 1
>                      from   t2
>                      where  t2.pkey = t1.pkey
>                      and    'name1' = any(name))
> group by t1.pkey;
> ```
>
> ```
> pkey | count
> ---: | ----:
>    3 |    16
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b6c89ff1b4cf33901cf7e3565431819a)*